# Showing that for a monic polynomial in $\Bbb R$ that $p(\overline r)= \overline{p(r)}$ form some $r$ root of p(x) not in $\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Trying to understand this snippet of a proof that the only irreducible polynomials in R are linear or quadratic:

Let $p(x)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial in R[x]. It has 
one root r in C. If $r \in \Bbb R$, then ($x − r$) divides $p(x)$ in $R$[$x$] and so $p(x) = x − r$.

If $r \notin R$, then
the complex conjugate $\overline r$ of $r$ is different from $r$ and,

since
$p(\overline r)= \overline{p(r)} = 0$, then ....

Why is this last statement true, supposing as written above that $p(x)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial in $R$[$x$].

Comment: If $r$ is a root of $p(x)$, then you have more stronging that $p(r)=0$ so you want to show that $p(\overline r)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true for any polynomial in $R[x]$.

Let $p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$. Then
$$
p(\overline x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n (\overline x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \overline{x^n} = \sum_{n=0}^N \overline{a_n x^n} = \overline{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n} = \overline{p(x)}.
$$
We used the fact that $a_n$'s are real, $\overline{zw} = \overline{z} \overline{w}$, and $\overline{z+w} = \overline{z} + \overline{w}$.